# DT_BOOL value of TRUE maps to 255 in a tinyint field. Why not 1?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SQL Server Integration Services 2008 to put a certain boolean value in the database, and originally I used the SSIS type of `DT_BOOL` (boolean).

However, in the database, the boolean value is being stored as a `tinyint` field (for legacy reasons). A boolean value of `TRUE` would be saved in the database as `255` (all bits on), instead of the more traditional value of 1.

Is there any way to force a `DT_BOOL` value of `TRUE` to map to 1 instead of 255? Or do I need to change the SQL field to `bit`, or use a numeric SSIS type like `DT_UI1`?

Answer (score 4):

Well you could add a further transformation task into your SSIS package to transform the DT_BOOL value of TRUE to 1 and an SSIS quuivalent of the SQL Server data type tinyint but of course this adds an additional step to your processing.

You would be far better off modifying your database data type to the more appoprriate bit data type in my opinion if this is indeed an option to you.

Comment: For now, I ended up using DT_I4 instead of DT_BOOL